# Running Java program gives errors I don't understand

Tags: java

I am in my first semester of CS classes. We were tasked with writing a simple program. It compiled fine but running it gave me errors that I do not yet understand. If someone could tell me what part of my program is causing this errors and give a possible solution, it would be much appreciated

**Command prompt feed**

> C:\Users\name\Documents\cs151fall2016>javac inclass.java
>
> C:\Users\name\Documents\cs151fall2016>java inclass Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: inclass : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
>
> C:\Users\name\Documents\cs151fall2016>

**Program being run**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class  inclass {

   public static void main (String[] args) {

     float age;
     float dogage;

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print ("Do you want to know your age in dog years? Enter your age!");
     System.out.flush();
     age = scan.nextInt();

     dogage = (float) age * 7;

     if (age < 6) 
         System.out.println ("Are you a prodigy?");
     else
         System.out.println ("Your age in dog years is:" + dogage);

   }
}
```

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: Hey, I can run the program successfully, without any error. Is that something you missed out in question part?